# How is show data in nested array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I want to just only show "A" : value or "B" : value or "C" : value

Like this:

Select divOne>select underOne

A : x1

A : x2

But show like this:

A:x1

B:y1

C:z1

A:x2

B:y2

C:z2

How could it be?

I tried key["A"] etc.

Jquery and array

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    "divOne": {
      "underOne": [{
          "A": "x1",
          "B": "y1",
          "C": "z1"
        },
        {
          "A": "x2",
          "B": "y2",
          "C": "z2"
        }

      ]
    },
    "divTwo": {
      "underThree": [{
          "A": "x5",
          "B": "y5",
          "C": "z5"
        },
        {
          "A": "x6",
          "B": "y6",
          "C": "z6"
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  var firstSelect = $('<select id="firstSelect"><option  >Select</option></select>').appendTo("#container");
  var secondSelect = $('<select id="secondSelect"> </select>').appendTo("#container");
  var results = $('<div id="results"> </div>').appendTo("#container");

  $.each(data, function(item, key) {
    firstSelect.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
  });

  firstSelect.on("change", function(e) {
    secondSelect.empty().append("<option value='' >select</option>").change();
    var item;
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected.length > 0) {
      item = data[selected];
      $.each(item, function(item, key) {
        secondSelect.append('<option >' + item + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });

  $("#secondSelect").on("change", function(e) {
    results.empty().append("<span></span>");
    var item1;
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        item1 = data[firstSelect.val()][selected];
        $.each(item1[i], function(item, key) {
          results.append('<span >' + item + '</span>:');
          results.append('<span >' + key + '</span></br>');
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? I get the exact expected output. `A:x1
B:y1
C:z1
A:x2
B:y2
C:z2`

Comment: fill `underOne` array only with `A`'s etc

Comment: @Matthi I don't want to get A:x1 B:y1 C:z1 A:x2 B:y2 C:z2 
I just A's value or B's o C's

Comment: @line88 but B or C will be need me. I will use them

Comment: then make one array of items `data: { A: [1,2,3...], B: [b1,b2,b3...], C: [c1,c2,c3...] }` and on `div` select change get data using `data['A']`

Comment: Sorry, didn't read well. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850412/merge-javascript-objects-in-array-with-same-key maybe?

Comment: @line88 That's not what I want. but thanks

Comment: @Matthi Kind of. But I use select boxes